# Please explain что ты?

Tags: перевод

Can you please explain what "нет, что ты" could be translated into?
I have tried the speech machines but they do not pick it up. Is this phase used a lot in the russian language?

Comment: See [нет, что вы](http://phraseology_ru_en.academic.ru/30306/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82,_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here expression "что ты!" is a short version of «что ты такое говоришь/предлагаешь!»
It means that previously expressed ideas absolutely unacceptable by answerer.
This expression normally used in speech.

Example:
— Слышь, программист, а ты умеешь писать вирусы?
— Нет, что ты! *(испуганно)*

Comment: большой Спасибо!

Comment: 1. «спасибо» is neuter, as most of words ending with -o. It also supposed to start from the lower case letter, unless it starts a sentence. So it is "Больш*ое* спасибо!"

Comment: 2. If this answer is good for you, you should "accept" it. It concerns all your answered questions. You can read *help->tour* on the upper line of the screen to learn how this site works.

Comment: Answer accepted. Sorry for the belated response. Please accept my apologies. Not intended to be rude in any way. If you notice that I am not inside the norm please educated me in what the norm is so I can adapt. I am new in this forum and not fully up to speed.

Comment: Oh, I am not offended, I understand you are a newbie here :). You can browse help->Help Center if you want to learn more about this site. [Enjoy](http://www.buzzfeed.com/susiearmitage/29-things-you-will-only-understand-if-you-studied-russian#.dmO1KlAPX) your Russian learning!

Comment: I like this forum a lot. The reach is extremely broad and the responses fast. Thanks again for the help!